# Jquery loading in Parent, using in popup?

Tags: jquery, popup, parent

I have a simple page index.php (parent) that loads an external js (index.js) file.

Some of the code in the js file is used on the index.php page, but other code I'd like to use in a new page (test.php) that is being opened as a popup.

The code in the index.js I have is :

```
$("li").on(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var Num = $(this).index();
        var nthChild = Num+1;
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

and it should interact with the `li` I have in the test.php

I'm using bpopup to open the popup page using this :

```
  $("#openPop").click(function(e) {
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            loadUrl: 'test.php',
        });
   });
```

If I add the JS to the popup page then it works, but I'd like to include it in the index.js loaded by index.php but interacting with test.php.

is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: `$("li").on(function(){` is incorrect code. You need to pass `event` name like `click` or `hover` as a first argument there to bind that particular `event`. Please let us know what you are achieving via that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your li code is incorrect already, below i put the function to a click event. What i've also done is bound it to the body, rather than an li that doesnt exist yet. It will still listen for the correct li's to be clicked though.

```
$("body").on('click', '#element_to_pop_up li', function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var Num = $(this).index();
        var nthChild = Num+1;
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
    }
});
```